# Why does the following python code throw a Memory error?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, package

Here is the code:

```
import itertools

num_cases = int(input())

answer_list = []

while num_cases>0:
    live_ans = []
    question_list = []
    nums = int(input())
    d1 = int(input())
    d2 = int(input())
    sample_space= {d1, d2}
    temp = []

    no_cases = 2**(nums-1)

    combs = itertools.product(sample_space, repeat = nums-1)

    for i in combs:
        temp.append(i)

    for i in temp:
        if sum(i) not in live_ans:
            live_ans.append(sum(i))
        else:
            pass
    live_ans.sort()
    answer_list.append(live_ans)
    num_cases -= 1

for i in answer_list:
    finalans = " ".join(map(str, i))
    print(finalans)
```

For small inputs like:

```
1
3
1
2
```

The program works just fine. Where as for a relatively larger input like:

```
1
58
69
24
```

It gives a memory error. I dont cite any reason for this as the code doesn't look memory consuming at all. Isn't it?

Comment: " I dont cite any reason for this as the code doesn't look memory consuming at all. Isn't it" It looks extremely memory consuming, you are materializing a cartesian product. This will give you someting on the order of O(2^k) memory usage, where K is `nums -1`.

Comment: Note, you don't need to materialize this list at all. Why are you doing that? Just iterate over `combs` directly when you are checking for the answer. That is the *whole point of itertools*, is that it provides memory-efficient iterators, but if you just put those in a list its defeats that. In any event, though, you will soon run into time efficiency problems as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your following lines:

```
no_cases = 2**(nums-1)
combs = itertools.product(sample_space, repeat = nums-1)
for i in combs:
    temp.append(i)
```

2**58 = 2.8823038e+17
You do the math on why it gets a memory error from here

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me an effective solution to this?

Comment: @IntoAbhi No I cannot because I do not know what your question is. I simply answered for you why your code is hitting a memory error

Comment: Here's the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/manasa-and-stones/problem

Comment: @IntoAbhi usually the point of these problems is to find a solution that isn't simply brute-force checking every answer in the possible answer space, that's what makes them a challenge.